# Apache rewrite condition for matching Query

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need a rewrite condition for returning e.g. 403, when a query contains characters, which are not in my "whitelisted" character class.
The query beginns with q=
So my attempt was:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/generic/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=[^a-z]+
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

It is working almost. Only problem is, when the query beginns with e.g. "a",
any following blacklisted characters don't trigger the rule

Example:

```
q=abc -> rule does not match -> fine
q=Abc -> rule matches -> fine
q=abC -> rule does not match -> not fine
```

So when the forbidden characters are not the first character after "q=", the rule is not working.

What am I missing? Can someone help me?

BR

Answer (score 1):

With your shown attempts, please try following htaccess rules file. 2 important points here, 1st you can use `^` in spite of `.*` in last forbidding Rule. 2nd is you need to use `NC` to cover lower case to match small and capital letters in regex.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/generic/  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=[^a-z]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

***OR*** use following rules to match exact query string use `^` and `$` anchors to match exact query string value:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/generic/  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^q=[^a-z]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Hi RavinderSingh13,
a-z is just an example, so [NC] is not needed, but thank you anyway :-)
Sadly, the mentioned regex you proposed, doesn't change the behaviour.
Still no match, when e.g. second character after "q=" is outside of "a-z", e.g. "A".
Only works as needed, when first chacter falls outside off pattern.
BR

Comment: @gnocchi01, could you plesse do provide an example of string which you want to match?

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13,
thanks for your support, I solved it the other way round and blocked some characters, instead of whitelisting all allowed.
Basically, I wanted to allow all a-zA-Z0-)äöüÖÄÜßáàéè and so on.
Thank you, this question is solved.
Solved with this rewritecond:
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)q=[^&]*[$/][^&]*